# It is possible to change default Blogger shareButtons icons?

Tags: css, layout, blogger, blogspot

I would like to change default blogger id='shareButtons' with my own icons but keep all default functionality.

Even I can do that: What will happen with mouseover effect?

Maybe i can use CSS or add img scr for this?

```
<b:if cond='data:top.showEmailButton'><a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-email' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=email&quot;' expr:title='data:top.emailThisMsg' target='_blank'><span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.emailThisMsg/></span></a></b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible since "blogger share button" served by a .css style from blogger system. Even you want to change it with CSS classes, the image will be stacked.

Answer (score 0):

For fixing the issue with the hover effect after replacing the default share button icons you can either do it by overriding the CSS or by doing changes in the HTML markup

For the overriding CSS approach , you can use !important directive on the :hover selector properties. Like for example , Blogger by default adds the following CSS for the Email share icon

```
a:hover.sb-email {
background-position: 0 -20px !important;
}
```

To override it , You can add following CSS

```
a:hover.sb-email {
background-position: 0 0 !important;
}
```

*Even though Blogger default CSS also has the !important directive but as the CSS we added is inline in the template , it will be able to negate the CSS Blogger adds via an external stylesheet.

The other approach is that you change the HTML markup . In that you can remove the classes by which Blogger adds its default CSS, To better understand , the HTML markup that you shared in your question

```
<b:if cond='data:top.showEmailButton'>
<a class='goog-inline-block share-button sb-email' expr:href='data:post.sharePostUrl + &quot;&amp;target=email&quot;' expr:title='data:top.emailThisMsg' target='_blank'>
<span class='share-button-link-text'><data:top.emailThisMsg/></span>
</a>
</b:if>
```

From it you can remove the following classes

**sb-email** - It is responsible for the hover effects

**share-button** - It is responsible for the default icons that are displayed for all share buttons